# XML: external entity in attribute not resolving

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE MYROOT PUBLIC "DummyText" "" [
    <!NOTATION txt PUBLIC 'some info'>
    <!ELEMENT MYROOT    (EXTERN+) >
    
    <!ELEMENT EXTERN    (#PCDATA) >
    <!ATTLIST EXTERN
        Ref ENTITY  #REQUIRED >
    
    <!ENTITY extern1 SYSTEM "test.txt" NDATA txt>
    <!ENTITY extern2 "Test string">
]>
<MYROOT>
    <EXTERN Ref="extern1">&extern2;</EXTERN>
</MYROOT>
```

I would like to get `EXTERN->Ref` external reference value. Here is my code:

```
var xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse,
    ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD
};
var doc = new XmlDocument();
using ( var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Temp\test.xml", xmlSettings) )
{
    doc.Load(xmlReader);
}

var externNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//EXTERN");
var extern_Content = externNode.InnerText;
var extern_Ref = externNode.Attributes["Ref"].InnerText;
```

`extern_Content` has the expected value.

`extern_Ref` does not have the expected value.

How can I get the info `test.txt` from the attribute?